# Fibrant objects of marked simplicial sets

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, higher-category-theory

Im reading the nlab article one the [Cartesian model structure on the category of marked simplicial sets over a simplicial set $S$](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/model+structure+for+Cartesian+fibrations#model_structure_on_marked_simplicial_sets). Here it is stated just below Proposition 3.1 which is a characterization of the fibrant objects. It says that a marked simplicial sets $X$ is fibrant if and only if $X \simeq Y$, where $Y \to S$ is a Cartesian fibration. The case $S=\Delta^0$, shows that the fibrant objects of $sSet^+$ are the $\infty$-categories, where the marked edges are the equivalences. I can't see why this is true. I have also tried to read the corresponding part in HTT, but it didn't help me.

Comment: Can you clarify what aspect of the proof in HTT you're having trouble with? My draft of Lurie switches $Y$ into $Z$ at some point, but other than that and the inherent ugliness of the marked model structure it seems to be pretty standard model category theory: the retract lemma to characterize the fibrants, fibrants turn weak equivalences into homotopy equivalences, and cofibrations enjoy the homotopy extension property.

Comment: It is not a proof in HTT, but rather a remark made in the nlab article i linked to. The one right after proposition 3.1. which reads:
"In particular, the fibrant objects of $sSet^+ \cong sSet^+/*$ are precisely the quasicategories in which the marked edges are precisely the equivalences."

Comment: I was talking about the proof of 3.1. Were you asking how the remark follows from 3.1? A Cartesian fibration over the point is a quasicategory, and the Cartesian edges are the equivalences.

Comment: Yes exactly! Tanks for the concise answer.